# trigger/bind jquery event for textbox on page load

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-ajax

I have a zip code textbox in view1 when the user enters zip code and click next to add more details I am passing zip code from view1 to view2. In view2 I need to display state and city based on the zip code entered. I have used keyup to get city and state based on zip entered. It works fine when I change zip code in view2.But dones not work  when i am coming from view1 to view2. I need to trigger event for zip code textbox on page load I mean when zip code is passed from view1 to view2. Right now  when I come from view1 to view2 only zip code display in its respective textbox, and city and state field don't display anything. How do I trigger an event for zip code textbox or bind to the existing event on page load?

```js
$(document).ready(function ()
        {
            $("#zip").keyup(function () {
                var el = $(this);

                if (el.val().length === 5) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type:'GET',
                         dataType: "json",
                        cache: true,
                        url: "../api/Getstatelist/" + el.val(),
                        success: function (html) {
                            $.each(html,function(key,value){
$('#state').append($('<option></option>').val(value.State).html(value.State));
});
$.each(html,function(key,value){
$('#city').append($('<option></option>').val(value.City).html(value.City));
});
                        }
                    }); 
                }
            });
  });
```

```html
<div>
            <div class="city-wrap">
                <select id="city">
                    <option value="">Select City first</option>
                </select>
                <label for="city">City</label>
            </div>
            <div class="state-wrap">
                <select id="state">
                    <option value="">Select State </option>
                </select>
                <label for="state">State</label>
            </div>
            <div class="zip-wrap">
               @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Zip, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "zip", @name = "zip" })
                <label for="zip">Zip</label>

            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution. Added on load function like below. I am not sure is this the right way to do. Any suggestions would be helpful.

```
  $( window ).on( "load", function() {
    var val = $('#zip').val();
if (val.length === 5) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type:'GET',
                         dataType: "json",
                        cache: true,
                        url: "../api/Getstatelist/" + val,
                        success: function (html) {
                            $.each(html,function(key,value){
 $('#state').append($('<option></option>').val(value.State).html(value.State));
});
$.each(html,function(key,value){
$('#city').append($('<option></option>').val(value.City).html(value.City));
});
                        }
                    }); 
                }

}
```